# how to put an array in the arguments of a bean or List<Bean> from other bins Spring?

Tags: java, spring

'I don't understand how to configure the Bin in such a way that it creates a Music Player from List<> of other bins.I know how to do it in Xml configuration, but I don't understand it through java annotations.    '

```
    package org;
    import org.music.Music;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Component("musicPlayer")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public class MusicPlayer {
        @Resource(name = "theList")'not sure what's right'
        private List<Music> musicList;
        @Value("${musicPlayer.name}")
        private String name;
        @Value("${musicPlayer.volume}")
        private int volume;
    
        public MusicPlayer(List<Music> list){
            this.musicList = list;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public int getVolume() {
            return volume;
        }
    
        public void playMusic(){
            for (Music music : musicList) {
                System.out.println("Playing: " + music.getSong());
            }
        }
    
        @PostConstruct
        public void doMyInit(){
            System.out.println("Open Stream");
        }
    
        @PreDestroy
        public void doMyDestroy(){
            System.out.println("Close Stream");
        }
    }
```

'I didn't find anything on the Internet.'

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `@Autowired List<Music> musics`;
2. Then somewhere create classes with `@Component` annotation that derived from Music class or return each one from a function using `@Bean` annotation.

It will do a trick for you.

Comment: you would have the OP to create a new annotated class, or a new Bean for every single song he wants to add? seriously?